# Mapping entities with fluent api on entity framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, orm, code-first, lambda

I have a question.

I have these two tables:
[image: Tables]

The principal table is User with Customer dependence.

The reverse engineer code first generated classes as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Customers = new List<Customer>();          
    }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

}

public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
    }

    ...

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

I made the following modification in the user class:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {          

    }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

Because the relationship is One-to–Zero-or-One.

The original mapping is this:

```
// Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithMany(t => t.Customers)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserID);
```

And the modified mapping is  this :

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithOptional(t => t.Customer)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserID"));
```

Is That correct?
If not, how would this mapping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct.

The best thing you can do - supposed you can change the database schema - is removing the `UserID` foreign key from the `Customer` table and then create the relationship in the database between the two primary keys so that `Customer.CustomerID` is the foreign key in the association.

Reverse Engineering should then automatically create the expected one-to-one relationship, like so:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    //...
}

//...

this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Customer);
```

If you can't change the database schema, your best bet is to only remove the collection `ICollection<Customer> Customers` from the `User` class and keep the relationship as one-to-many.

The reason for all this is that EF only supports shared primary key one-to-one associations, but not foreign key one-to-one associations. (The latter one you can only "fake" by removing the collection, but it's still one-to-many from EF viewpoint.)

You can read more about one-to-one associations with EF and its limitations here:

- [One-to-one Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx)
- [One-to-one Foreign Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Slauma, I don't understand why removing the foreign key of the customer table. What I did in this example was his second option.

Comment: @Gus: No, it's not his second option. His second option ("one-to-one foreign key association") uses `WithMany()`, not `WithOptional`. That's a one-to-many relationship with a removed collection, i.e. only one navigation property. Also, you cannot use `MapKey("UserID")` if you have a property called `UserID`. You must use `HasForeignKey` then, like shown in Mortezza's example.